# Execute a python script from firefox, on a very specific app, just to let firefox provide the graphical IDE

Tags: python, firefox, plugins, external-script

So, I've been searching the topic for quite a while, but I am unable to find out whether it is possible or not. I suspect not, but I need to be sure.

What I'm doing:
I am building a fancy web app that uses xml, xsl and javascript. However, I need to do some transformation to a text file to convert it into a proper xml file. To do this, I use a python script.

What I need:
I am working to make as easy as possible the use of the app, but this gets kind of destroyed when the user has to execute a terminal script before anything. I need a graphical IDE for python, but I just don't have time to learn how to make one, and I would love that the entire app would work within the same web environment, much more intuitive for the user. Then, a really easy way to do that would be to use Firefox as the IDE, for example choosing the file to be transformed through it, and launching from there the python script.

What I require:
I need compatibility only with Firefox. But of course any system capable to install Python and Firefox should work as well. The user would happily install both programs, as long as they have interest in the app.

What I don't know:
Is that possible, to execute an external python script? If not, for security reasons I imagine, is there any way for the user to allow it? Maybe through the installation of a plugin?

- maybe http://mozex.mozdev.org/ is what I am looking for?

Thanks!

Gerard

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is possible to execute an external python script. You can use a [simpleServer](http://docs.python.org/library/simplehttpserver.html) ([example](http://fragments.turtlemeat.com/pythonwebserver.php)) that receives a (Ajax) request from your page and calls a [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) or os.startfile to launch the script. In fact, you can call the function itself from within the server and return the result (e.g. as [json](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-json)) to the page and use your javascript to handle it.

Comment: Yes, this is an option, but this requires that the user executes the python script (in this case, a server, right now, just a script), and after start the .html file with the firefox. 

With the added complexity that after the whole process, the user should close the server. So actually I wouldn't be simplifying the process (my original goal).
(thx for answering!)

Comment: I see you want the user to open and close just one file/program. If you can let the server run continuously, you could make one script, that checks if the server is already running (and starts it if not), and also starts `os.starfile('interface.html')`. That way, the user only sees the (webbrowser) interface, which itself communicates through the   small server with your Python scripts. If the user closes the browser, the server keeps running, but that does not matter (very small). The next time the main script is run, no new server needs to be instantiated.

Comment: The options that I have would be:

a) web server handling the comunication between the IDE (firefox) and the script (python)

b) pythonext, so that the user could (I ignore how, but I guess it can be done) can use FF to execute the scrypt, sending also for example the file to process.

c) a standalone script, with a GUI, so that the user has an easy way to use it.

Comment: The a) option requires that the user installs firefox and a server, or a python script that builds a server itself. My intention is to have one computer per user, so that every user should start the server at least once.

The b) option, the user needs to install FF and the extension. By far this is the more comfortable option.

c) needs the user to start 2 programs, very similar than the a) option. Between a) and c), I'm not sure what is a better option. a) avoids me to build an IDE, but I'd say brings more complexity to the user. b) option is the best, but it is totally obscure to me.

Comment: pythonext limits the use to FireFox. If you do not have a good reason to limit yourself at this stage, then I suggest you don't. Depending on the complexity of your program, a GUI can be an interesting option, also because you can use [Py2Exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) to create a standalone version of it for which no Python installation is necessary. Personally I have done both, but became a fan of the use of a browser as IDE (trhough your option a), because of the flexibility of the programming of the GUI and the ease of using jquery.

Comment: The server does not have to be installed on all computers if they have a network-connection: you can install your python program, including server, only on one computer and let the users access it. Or do as I said before: let the user open a main-script, that starts the server (if it is not already running) AND the browser at once.

Comment: The GUI is probably the best way to go. Anything with an EXE would destroy the beauty of a browser, i.e. you don't care about the OS. To have a server implies either that I maintain a web server, or that the user needs to install this web server (or the institution, or whoever). To much complexity. Probably, by the time the program is finished (or let's say mature), the webapps would be more popular, and new capabilities will appear that will allow to interact the way I would like. Let's see what I will do, but unless pythonext convinces me, I think I will go for the python GUI. Thx!

Comment: OK, just try to keep the 'view' (GUI) part as much as possible separated from the rest of your code ('model'). This best practice makes things quite easy if any time in the future you decide to use another way to interface your application.

Answer (score 1):

If you're after actually using python in firefox, rather than having the server side written in python (although the webserver can of course be running locally), I would guess [pythonext](http://code.google.com/p/pythonext/) (used to be [pyxpcomext](http://pyxpcomext.mozdev.org/)) is what you need.

Comment: I can smell that this is what I was looking for. I'm gonna check what can you do with it, thanks a lot! (dammit, it is not python3, I guess after all I will have to re-write everything and definitively abandon python3, something I didn't want to, but it is like python3 is just not an option right now (for instance, no SOAP client))